# python opcua BadDeviceFailure (error 0x808B0000)

Tags: python, plc, opc-ua

while using the python library for the opcua communication I get this error "BadDeviceFailure: There has been a failure in the device/data source that generates the value that has affected the value." after 15 minutes from the start of the script.
The opc-ua server target is Beckhoff TF6100.
I'd like to know what is the meaning of this error, what can raise it and how to handle it, thank you very much.

Comment: What library is "the python library"?

Comment: The "opcua" python package: https://python-opcua.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Beckhoff TF6100 I am 99% sure that your problem is related to the AMS net ID of your target system.

Click on the 3 dots (...) next to AMS Net ID in your Interface properties windows and select the right target.

hope this answer helps you or anyone trying to figure this out

BadDeviceFailure = 0x808B0000
Bad Device Failure = 808B0000

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjdxB.png)

For future error codes references.

https://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdknet/2.5.8/html/classUnifiedAutomation_1_1UaBase_1_1StatusCodes.html#a7fa424c0a9b0f20740d7000492767819